# How to preserve the data type witha mixed data type array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array that its initialized as an `empty` array. Inside the array, there will be some values that are `integer` and other that are `floats`. After a `for` cycle, all the output are `floats` (scientific notation) regardless if the previous data was an `integer`. I need the integers to stay as integers.

Here is how the `for` cycle looks like:

```
arr = np.empty(arr_size)

co_point = np.uint8(arr_size[1]/2)

for k in range(arr_size[0]):
   p1_idx = int(k%np.array(first_list).shape[0])
   p2_idx = int((k+1)%np.array(first_list).shape[0])

   arr[k, 0:co_point] = first_list[p1_idx][0:co_point]

   arr[k, co_point:] = first_list[p2_idx][co_point:]
```

`first_list` is a list that cointains other lists with numbers.

For example, the output of this would be:

```
>>arr
array([[1.0e+02, 1.0e-05, 1.0e-02, 3.0e-01, 3.2e+01]])
```

And the desired output is something like this:

```
>>arr
array([[100, 1.0e-05, 0.001, 0.3, 32]])
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That is not possible. Numpy arrays are homogeneous: all elements have the same data type.

Comment: Use a list. Add the `numpy` tag please.  For some reason I cannot edit the question

Comment: And isn't there any way of getting, for example, the initial data type of the elements so that after the loop I can check each data type and make any changes, if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround that does the trick, but I'm sure that there are better or more optimal answers. I'll share it here for anyone that also has some similar issue.

The original code is this:

```
arr = np.empty(arr_size)

co_point = np.uint8(arr_size[1]/2)

for k in range(arr_size[0]):
   p1_idx = int(k%np.array(first_list).shape[0])
   p2_idx = int((k+1)%np.array(first_list).shape[0])

   arr[k, 0:co_point] = first_list[p1_idx][0:co_point]

   arr[k, co_point:] = first_list[p2_idx][co_point:]
```

I added an aditional array of same dimentions of the `arr array` that holds only the data type of the `first_list` `list`.

```
dtypes = np.empty(arr_size,dtype=type)
for x in range(arr_size[0]):
  for y in range(arr_size[1]):
    dtypes[x,y]=type(first_list[x][y])
```

Then, when the loop is finished I need to recast the values of arr to the original types of `first_list`, but because `arr` forces the data type, I created a new list with an auxiliary list to append all the values.

```
r_arr = []
for x in range(arr_size[0]):
   aux = []
   for y in range(arr_size[1]):
      aux.append(dtypes[x,y](arr[x,y]))
   r_arr.append(aux)
```

The trick is that having an array that stores `dtype=type` data type, enables you to actually do `dtypes[x,y](arr[x,y])` in the same way that you would do `type(1.13)`.

Hope its clear and you find it useful!